# Player stops if even a single file does not exist from HLS M3U8 playlist

Tags: media-player, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Suppose I have a big m3u8 playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10,
2720.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2730.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2740.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2750.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2800.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2810.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2820.mpg
#EXTINF:10,
2830.mpg
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

If one single file (for example 2810.mpg) is missing, player will stop and not jump on next available file (2820.mpg) like I would want it to behave. Is there any way I can tell HLS to behave the way I want to? (I want to achieve this by altering playlist if possible)

Answer (score 1):

> Any Media Segment that is specified in a Playlist loaded by a client
>   MUST be available for immediate download (HLS Draft - 6.2.1)

If it doesn't exist, don't put it in the playlist in the first place.